# Send a request if Amazon Lambda function is successful or unsuccessful

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My Amazon Lambda function (in Python) is called when an object `123456` is created in S3's `input_bucket`, do a transformation in the object and saves it in `output_bucket`.

I would like to notify my main application if the request was successful or unsuccessful. For example, a POST `http://myapp.com/successful/123456` if the processing is successful and `http://myapp.com/unsuccessful/123456` if its not.

One solution I thought is to create a second Amazon Lambda function that is triggered by a put event in `output_bucket`, and it to do the *successful* POST request. This solves half of the problem because but I can't trigger the *unsuccessful* POST request.

Maybe AWS has a more elegant solution using a parameter in Lambda or a service that deals with these types of notifications. Any advice or point in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: input_bucket--> What is this S3?

Comment: @Nambari Yes, the buckets are S3

Comment: I don't think there is any elegant AWS solution, unless you re-architect, something like your lambda sends message to SQS or some intermediatery messaging service with STATUS and then interemdeiatery invokes POST to your application. If you still want to go with your way of solving, you might need to configure "DeadLetter queue" to do error handling in failure cases (note that use cases described here are not comprehensive, so need to make sure it covers your case) like described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html

Comment: Whichever language you write your lambda in, will have a try-catch. Send a POST from there itself?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I would highly discourage that approach, unless application is prototype. In general keeping responsibilities separate is best way to maintain code and scale.

Comment: @Nambari Thanks! That was what I was looking for: A DeadLetter to SNS that will take care of POSTing the request to the main app. Please can you post your solution as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: @Victor Glad it helped. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any elegant AWS solution, unless you re-architect, something like your lambda sends message to SQS or some intermediatery messaging service with STATUS and then interemdeiatery invokes POST to your application.

If you still want to go with your way of solving, you might need to configure "DeadLetter queue" to do error handling in failure cases (note that use cases described here are not comprehensive, so need to make sure it covers your case) like described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html).

Answer (score 2):

Few possible solutions which I see as elegant

- Using [SNS Topic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html): From your transformation lambda, trigger a SNS topic, with success/unsuccess message, where SNS will call a HTTP/HTTPS endpoint with message payload. The advantage here is, your transformation lambda is loosely coupled with endpoint trigger and only connected through messaging.
- Using [Lambda Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-step-functions-build-distributed-applications-using-visual-workflows/):

  > You could arrange to run a Lambda function every time a new object is uploaded to an S3 bucket. This function can then kick off a state machine execution by calling *StartExecution*. The advantage in using step functions is that you can coordinate the components of your application as series of steps in a visual workflow.